# Detect Kerberoasting activity

Tags: account-security, kerberos

I am working to detect kerberoasting activity and I am referring this [link](https://adsecurity.org/?p=3458).
It states that an account cannot be requesting several different service names within a second or two of each other. What is the threshold for this? I do see some account accessing 3 SPNs in 1 second.